# how to get video from a "USB3 Vision" device?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to get a camera feed from this microscope device through Python Tkinter.

[image]

I have tried using cv2 VideoCapture function, but it did not show the image.

```
class RunningStatusFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        ################## Camera Feed ##################
        self.camera_frame = LabelFrame(self, text="Camera Feed",
                                    width=800, height=600)
        self.camera_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.camera_feed = Label(self.camera_frame)
        self.camera_feed.pack(fill=BOTH)

        self.progress = IntVar(self)
        self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.showFrame()

        ################## Progress Bar #################
        self.progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self,
                                orient=HORIZONTAL,
                                length=150,
                                maximum=100,
                                mode='determinate',
                                variable=self.progress)
        self.progress_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

        ################## Laser Status ##################
        Label(self, text="    Laser:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.laser_status = Label(self, text="ON", fg="#f00")
        self.laser_status.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.updateInfo()

    def updateInfo(self):
        '''
        Function to update information.
        '''
        if self.parent.parent.select() == ".!notebook.!autorunframe":
            pass
        self.after(300, self.updateInfo)

    def showFrame(self):
        '''
        Update camera feed.
        '''
        frame = self.cam.read()
        if frame[0] == False:
            return None
        frame = imutils.resize(frame[1], width=400)
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)

        self.camera_feed.imgtk = imgtk
        self.camera_feed.configure(image=imgtk)
        self.camera_feed.after(20, self.showFrame)
    
    def setProgress(self, value):
        '''
        Changes progress bar status.
        '''
        self.progress.set(value)
```

This works for the webcam from my laptop, but somehow (perhaps because my microscope is an imaging device) it does not show anything.
Anyone have done something like this?
Any advice would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: If you bring up the Camera app, can you select this device?  It may advertise itself as a still image device, not a streaming device.

Comment: `assert self.cam.isOpened()`

Comment: Either instsll the allied vision windows/Linux drivers if they exist (e.g. V4L2) or,. which I would strongly recommend, use the Vimba SDK to get access to the device and all its features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a **"USB3 Vision"** device.

"USB3 Vision" is a specific industry standard, but not part of the USB standard.

USB3 Vision is **not a webcam**. USB webcams are Unified Video Class (UVC), a device class specified in the standard.

Windows certainly doesn't come with a driver for USB3 Vision. It only comes with UVC.

You're gonna need to talk to the manufacturer and get a driver for your video device. And then that driver still might not present as a video device in Windows media APIs, but you might have to talk to the driver directly.

You *could* try VideoCapture with the `cv.CAP_XIMEA` flag... but I've never tried that. XIMEA makes devices that do USB3 Vision. If you're lucky, the OpenCV `videoio` backend for XIMEA *might* work for your device too.

And definitely check out the comment above by Micka. He strikes me as knowledgeable about these devices.